# MonoTouch runtime test to see if it's running in the simulator

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, simulator

Probably really simple, but I can't find an answer - how can I do a check at runtime (using MonoTouch) to make sure I'm in the iPhone simulator (or not) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
static bool InSimulator ()
{
    return Runtime.Arch == Arch.SIMULATOR;
}
```

This is from here: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/recipes/General/Projects/Environment_Checks